# Audio Streaming - Capturing and reading microphone data

Tags: java, audio, audio-streaming, microphone

I'm trying to get microphone data from my default microphone, and send it to another program on my computer. The sending works, but I'm not reading any data from my microphone, here is the output. The output is the same regardless if  I read the data or not.

```
Output:
 This program: [B@ec7777
 Reciever program: b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\.....
```

```
import java.lang.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.net.SocketException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.zip.DataFormatException;

import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;

import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.TargetDataLine;
import javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem.*;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

class mainclass {
    public static int buffer = 1472;
    public static byte[] data = new byte[buffer]; 
    private static AudioFormat format = new AudioFormat(10100.0f, 16, 1, true, true);
    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SocketException, UnknownHostException,IOException, DataFormatException, InterruptedException, LineUnavailableException  {
        DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket();
        InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("my.ipa.ddr.ess");

        TargetDataLine microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);
        int numBytesRead;
        DatagramPacket packet;
        microphone.start();
        ByteArrayOutputStream out  = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
            numBytesRead = microphone.read(data, 0, data.length);
            out.write(data,0,numBytesRead);
            System.out.println(data);
            packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, myport);
            socket.send(packet);
        }
        microphone.stop();
        microphone.close();
    }
}
```

I get a LineUnavailableException if I don't throw it.

```
aud2.java:115: error: unreported exception LineUnavailableException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 
   TargetDataLine microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);
//                                                          ^ pointing at (
```

Comment: Please show the full stack trace of you exception.

Comment: @jmizv Error without throwing exception: aud2.java:115: error: unreported exception LineUnavailableException; must be caught or declared to be thrown 
TargetDataLine microphone = AudioSystem.getTargetDataLine(format);

Answer (score 0):

The `AudioFormat` you have listed seems very unlikely to be valid.

44100 is a much more common sample rate. Also, if you are using 16-bit encoding, and are recording mono, you will have 2-bytes per frame, not 1 as specified.

My guess is this being off would be consistent with getting a "line unavailable" exception. There may be other issues. But having an `AudioFormat` that Java supports is still a necessary first step.

If you need to use a slower sample rate, 11025 is in the vicinity and might be supported on your system. Also, perhaps 8000. Maybe 16,000. But I haven't delved deeply into alternate sample rates.

There's info on testing if audio formats are supported or not in the tutorial [Using Files and Format Converters](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/converters.html)

For my laptop's mike (when using the default on this laptop), I use a very plain vanilla settings, sometimes known as "CD Quality". The specs are as follows:

- encoding: AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED
- sample rate: 44100
- sample size in bits: 16
- channels: 2
- frame size: 4
- big endian: false

If for sure you have mono, *channels* would be 1 and *frame size* would be 2.